# SQL - sorting data according to the first priority when using LIKE in Clause

Tags: php, mysql, sql, sorting

After googling I could not find my answer to sort data according to the priority when using `like` in `clause`

I am using the following query to sort and view data:

```
SELECT    i.name,i.add_time,round(i.price),s.store_address
FROM      store_items i,stores s
WHERE     i.store_id = s.store_id 
AND       (lower(i.name) LIKE '%samsung glaxy%'
   OR lower(i.name) LIKE '%samsung%'
   OR lower(i.name) LIKE '%glaxy%')
ORDER BY  i.price ASC LIMIT 0,25
```

How I can sort resulting rows firstly for **Samsung Galaxy** first `like` operator as first priority, and then rows for **Samsung** and **Galaxy** as second priority?

**Please Note:**

*First priority* means that result rows should be shown firstly and *second priority* means that other resulted rows should be shown after

I have to fit it in my PHP function.

@10086'answer I am not able to fit it in `PHP CODE`

My PHP code is:

```
$sort = $_COOKIE['sort'];
$price_sort = $_COOKIE['price_sort'];
$currency_value = $_COOKIE['currency_value'];

if (!isset($_GET['number'])) {
       $limit = 0;
}else{
      $limit = filter_var($_GET['number'], FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
}

 $keyword_exp = explode(" ", $keyword); //separating keywords
 $like = ""; //for use like clause for every keyword
 $case = ""; // for priority selection case in query order
 $case_inc = 2;
 foreach ($keyword_exp as $value) {
          $like .= "AND lower(i.name) like '%$value%'"; 
          $case .= "WHEN lower(i.name) like '%$value%' THEN $case_inc";
          $case_inc += 1;
 } 
  //query performing to show result
  $sql_query = "SELECT i.name 'title',i.add_time 'time',round(i.price) 'price',round(i.new_price) 'new_price',s.store_address 'address' FROM store_items i,stores s WHERE i.store_id = s.store_id $like ORDER BY CASE WHEN lower(i.name) LIKE '%$keyword%' THEN 1 $case END ASC LIMIT 0,25";
  $query = mysql_query($sql_query) or die(mysql_error());
  while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) :
               extract($row);
  endwhile;
```

My SQL query in PHP code gives me following error:

> You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near 'lower(i.name) like '%refurbished%' THEN 3 END ASC LIMIT 0,25' at line 1

Comment: What do you mean by priority?

Comment: Show some sample data and expected output

Comment: _first priority_ means that result rows should be shown firstly and _second priority_ means that other resulted rows should be shown after

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your queries are not going to be as fast as they could because:

1. You use the `lower` function when `LIKE` is already case insensitive. `select 'a' LIKE 'A'` will return `true`
2. Using a column as the argument of a function in your WHERE forces the server to bypass its index and process the row: eg: `lower(i.name)`. This should be avoided in general

If you have MySQL 5.6+, and if `store_items.name` is of type *CHAR*, *VARCHAR* or *TEXT*, then add a *FULLTEXT* index to your `name` column to optimize it for text searches.

```
ALTER TABLE store_items ADD FULLTEXT fulltext_name (name);
```

Then modify your query to use the `MATCH...AGAINST` syntax:

```
SELECT i.name,i.add_time,round(i.price),s.store_address
FROM store_items i JOIN stores s ON i.store_id = s.store_id
WHERE MATCH(i.name) AGAINST('samsung galaxy')
```

This search will return all rows that have at least one of the two words `samsung` and `galaxy`.  Rows that have both words will be higher in the result set.

[From the docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-search.html):

> MATCH() takes a comma-separated list that names the columns to be
>   searched. AGAINST takes a string to search for, and an optional
>   modifier that indicates what type of search to perform
>
> ...
>
> Full-text indexes can be used only with MyISAM tables. (In MySQL 5.6
>   and up, they can also be used with InnoDB tables.) Full-text indexes
>   can be created only for CHAR, VARCHAR, or TEXT columns

Comment: Please can you tell me how I can add FULLTEXT index

Comment: This query is giving me many errors please can you suggest me how I can run this query?

Comment: I've edited the query to use `JOIN` to bind the tables. Does that help?  Did you add a `FULLTEXT` index on `store_items.name`?

Comment: Yes I added `FullTEXT` index

Comment: Awesome, query is working and it's speed is faster. But why I should use `JOIN` instead of `,` between the tow tables?

Comment: Can i avoid `+samsung +glaxy` and can use `samsung glaxy` instead?

Comment: To your 1st question: I've never actually compared speeds between `from tbl1 t1, tbl2 t2 where t1.id=t2.id` and `from tbl1 t1 join tbl2 t2 on t1.id=t2.id`. I don't know which is faster. I prefer the `join` syntax because it puts all of my table-joining instructions together in the `on` clause, and I can still use the `where` clause to filter rows from the joined table. It feels odd to use `where` to join the tables (even though it works) because its primary purpose is to filter.  Anyway, like I said I've never benchmarked speeds.

Comment: To your 2nd question: `samsung glaxy` means give me rows that have one or the other. The most relevant results (rows that contain both) come higher.  The `+` operator causes the server to *require* the tables to have these words, so you will get fewer results but all results will have both words. It's up to your preference. See https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/fulltext-boolean.html for detail

Comment: Thank you very very much for your answer and helping me for a lot and giving me your important time, this is your owe on me... thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

Use `CASE WHEN`:

```
SELECT    i.name,i.add_time,round(i.price),s.store_address
FROM      store_items i,stores s
WHERE     i.store_id = s.store_id 
AND       (lower(i.name) LIKE '%samsung glaxy%' OR lower(i.name) LIKE '%samsung%' OR lower(i.name) LIKE '%glaxy%')
ORDER BY
CASE WHEN lower(i.name) LIKE '%samsung glaxy%' THEN 1
     WHEN lower(i.name) LIKE '%samsung%' THEN 2
     WHEN lower(i.name) LIKE '%glaxy%' THEN 3
     ELSE 4 END,
i.price ASC
LIMIT 0,25
```

Comment: I am trying it now

Comment: Try: `"AND lower(i.name) like '%$value%'"` -> `" AND lower(i.name) like '%$value% '"` and `"WHEN lower(i.name) like '%$value%' THEN $case_inc"` -> `" WHEN lower(i.name) like '%$value%' THEN $case_inc "`

Comment: This search will be slower for a couple of reasons: (1) heavy use of the `LIKE` operator means a lot of comparisons, (2) the use of the column as the argument to a function (`lower(i.name)`) means the server cannot use its indices to optimize the query, and (3) the use of `lower` which is not needed because `LIKE` is not case sensitive.  I would suggest adding a `FULLTEXT` index and using the `MATCH...AGAINST` syntax as I suggested in my solution.  Or at least comparing the two approaches to select the fastest search.

Comment: @BeetleJuice Please can your tell me how to add FULLTEXT index